# Javascript looping through array with a promises function returning values in random order

Tags: javascript, api, for-loop, asynchronous, promise

My code is intended to loop through an array of sports team IDs to use them to compile various information from an API then add HTML to my page to display the most recently finished game for each team. It is working and looking great EXCEPT: the results are appearing in on my page in a random order each time I refresh. I'm thinking this has something to do with the loop moving to the next iteration quickly, while the responses from the server are coming back at random times. I expect the result to be "Patriots" first, then "Steelers" etc but the result is random, with Patriots hardly ever coming up first.

Also, I'm very new to JS, so I'm sure there is a ton I could do to make this better, so thank you in advance!

```
//Define the teams I want scores from and their API reference numbers.
let teams = new Map();
teams.set("Patriots", 134920);
teams.set("Steelers", 134925);
teams.set("Bruins", 134830);
teams.set("Penguins", 134844);
teams.set("Celtics", 134860);
teams.set("Red Sox", 135252);
teams.set("Huskers", 136923);

let teamArr = Array.from(teams.values());
for (i = 0; i < teamArr.length; i++) {
    console.log(teamArr[i]);
}

//Get the team data so that we can pull the logo image.
async function getTeamData(teamID) {
    let result = await fetch(`https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/lookupteam.php?id=${teamID}`)
    let teamData = await result.json();
    return teamData.teams[0];
}

//Get the info for the teams last game.
async function getLastGame(teamID) {
    let result = await fetch(`https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/eventslast.php?id=${teamID}`)
    const lastGames = await result.json();
    const lastGame = lastGames.results[0];
    return lastGame;
};

//Populate the final scores with new HTML after pulling all the info from the API.
for (let i = 0; i < teamArr.length; i++) {
    let homeTeam, awayTeam, homeTeamData, awayTeamData, homeTeamLogo, gameDay;
    getLastGame(teamArr[i])
    .then(lastGame => {
        gameDay = lastGame.dateEvent;
        homeTeam = {
            name: lastGame.strHomeTeam,
            id: lastGame.idHomeTeam,
            score: lastGame.intHomeScore,
        };
        awayTeam = {
            name: lastGame.strAwayTeam,
            id: lastGame.idAwayTeam,
            score: lastGame.intAwayScore
        }; //This is all the info we need except for the team icons.
    }).then(result => {
        homeTeamData = getTeamData(homeTeam.id)
        return homeTeamData; 
    }).then(result => {
        homeTeam.logo = result.strTeamBadge;
    }).then(() => {
        awayTeamData = getTeamData(awayTeam.id)
        return awayTeamData;
    }).then(result => {
        awayTeam.logo = result.strTeamBadge; //After getting who was home and who was away, these let us pull and put the right icon in the table.
    }).then(() => {
        let html = `    <tr>
                            <th><img src="%awayImg%" alt="Away" id="${i}-away" class="team-logo"></th>
                            <th><div class="at-vs">@</div></th>
                            <th><img src="%homeImg" alt="Home" id="${i}-home" class="team-logo"></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><div class="away-score">%awayScore%</div></th>
                            <th><div class="gameday">%gameDay%</div></th>
                            <th><div class="home-score">%homeScore%</div></th>
                        </tr>`;
        let newhtml = html.replace(`%awayImg%`, awayTeam.logo + "/preview");
        newhtml = newhtml.replace(`%homeImg`, homeTeam.logo + "/preview");
        newhtml = newhtml.replace(`%awayScore%`, awayTeam.score);
        newhtml = newhtml.replace(`%gameDay%`, gameDay);
        newhtml = newhtml.replace(`%homeScore%`, homeTeam.score);

        document.querySelector(`.past-games-table`).insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, newhtml);

    })
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you want is to make concurrent requests to get the data but still show them in a certain order no matter when they arrive.

Right now you are making all your requests one right after the other and showing the results as you get them. This means that the order in which the results are shown is unpredictable, any of the previous requests can finish before any of the subsequent ones and your data will be shown out of order.

Try running this snippet multiple times, the display order is unpredictable:

*Note, in the examples below I'm using some fake functions to represent the requesting of data and displaying it. `fakeRequest` is a function that can represent all but the last function in your promise chain (all the logic you use to get and build your team data) and `fakeDisplay` is function that can represent the last part of your chain that appends HTML and displays the data.*

```js
const fakeRequest = n => new Promise(
  resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`requesting ${n}`);
    resolve(n);
  }, Math.random() * 1000)
);

const fakeDisplay = n => console.log(`displaying ${n}`);

// all requests are made one after the other
// and as soon as a request is done, we display
// the data, no matter which request that is
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  fakeRequest(i).then(fakeDisplay);
}
```

The main issue here is that your displaying logic is tied together with the logic that gets the team data. Splitting this behavior would allow you to tackle your problem in multiple ways.

One way to fix this is to not make a request (and not display the data) until the previous request+display operation is finished:

```js
const fn = async () => {
  // note: using await is only valid in an async function
  const fakeRequest = n => new Promise(
    resolve => setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`requesting ${n}`);
      resolve(n);
    }, Math.random() * 1000)
  );

  const fakeDisplay = n => console.log(`displaying ${n}`);

  // make each request and wait for it to finish
  // then display the result and start next request 
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const item = await fakeRequest(i);
    fakeDisplay(item);
  }
}

fn();
```

Another way to alleviate this is to wait until all your requests are finished before displaying all the results at once (by using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)):

```js
const fakeRequest = n => new Promise(
  resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`requesting ${n}`);
    resolve(n);
  }, Math.random() * 1000)
);

const fakeDisplay = n => console.log(`displaying ${n}`);

// make the requests one after the other
// and save all the promises in an array
const promises = []
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  promises.push(fakeRequest(i));
}

// then use a built-in utility Promise.all to
// display all the results once they all arrive
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(results => {
    for (const item of results) {
      fakeDisplay(item);
    }
  })
```

The main issue with this is that your UI will not show anything until all requests are done which can take some time and might not be the ideal experience.

Perhaps your UX would be best if you make all requests around the same time but still show the results as they arrive, in the right the order.

```js
const fn = async () => {
  const fakeRequest = n => new Promise(
    resolve => setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`requesting ${n}`);
      resolve(n);
    }, Math.random() * 1000)
  );

  const fakeDisplay = n => console.log(`displaying ${n}`);

  // make the requests one after the other
  // and save all the promises in an array
  const promises = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    promises.push(fakeRequest(i));
  }

  // loop through the promises and resolve each
  // one and display the data
  for await (const item of promises) {
    fakeDisplay(item);
  }
}

fn();
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, and with a couple different ways of solving it. I ended up getting the behavior correct using the promises.all method. Much appreciated!

Comment: @badlytested glad to help, happy JavaScripting :)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two patterns that achieve the same thing. Here is your code refactored with `async` `await`

```
//Define the teams I want scores from and their API reference numbers.
let teams = new Map();
teams.set("Patriots", 134920);
teams.set("Steelers", 134925);
teams.set("Bruins", 134830);
teams.set("Penguins", 134844);
teams.set("Celtics", 134860);
teams.set("Red Sox", 135252);
teams.set("Huskers", 136923);

let teamArr = Array.from(teams.values());
for (i = 0; i < teamArr.length; i++) {
    console.log(teamArr[i]);
}

//Get the team data so that we can pull the logo image.
async function getTeamData(teamID) {
    let result = await fetch(`https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/lookupteam.php?id=${teamID}`)
    let teamData = await result.json();
    return teamData.teams[0];
}

//Get the info for the teams last game.
async function getLastGame(teamID) {
    let result = await fetch(`https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/eventslast.php?id=${teamID}`)
    const lastGames = await result.json();
    const lastGame = lastGames.results[0];
    return lastGame;
};

//Populate the final scores with new HTML after pulling all the info from the API.
for (let i = 0; i < teamArr.length; i++) {
    let homeTeam, awayTeam, homeTeamData, awayTeamData, homeTeamLogo, gameDay;
    const lastGame = await getLastGame(teamArr[i]);
    gameDay = lastGame.dateEvent;
    homeTeam = {
        name: lastGame.strHomeTeam,
        id: lastGame.idHomeTeam,
        score: lastGame.intHomeScore,
    };
    awayTeam = {
        name: lastGame.strAwayTeam,
        id: lastGame.idAwayTeam,
        score: lastGame.intAwayScore
    }; //This is all the info we need except for the team icons.
    homeTeamData = await getTeamData(homeTeam.id);
    homeTeam.logo = homeTeamData.strTeamBadge;
    awayTeamData = await getTeamData(awayTeam.id);
    awayTeam.logo = awayTeamData.strTeamBadge; //After getting who was home and who was away, these let us pull and put the right icon in the table.
    let html = `    <tr>
                        <th><img src="%awayImg%" alt="Away" id="${i}-away" class="team-logo"></th>
                        <th><div class="at-vs">@</div></th>
                        <th><img src="%homeImg" alt="Home" id="${i}-home" class="team-logo"></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><div class="away-score">%awayScore%</div></th>
                        <th><div class="gameday">%gameDay%</div></th>
                        <th><div class="home-score">%homeScore%</div></th>
                    </tr>`;
    let newhtml = html.replace(`%awayImg%`, awayTeam.logo + "/preview");
    newhtml = newhtml.replace(`%homeImg`, homeTeam.logo + "/preview");
    newhtml = newhtml.replace(`%awayScore%`, awayTeam.score);
    newhtml = newhtml.replace(`%gameDay%`, gameDay);
    newhtml = newhtml.replace(`%homeScore%`, homeTeam.score);

    document.querySelector(`.past-games-table`).insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, newhtml);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do in `async` functions is to `await` the resolution of a Promise. In a `for` loop, this means you won't continue executing the loop until your previous iteration has resolved. Here's a trivial example. You will likely have a similar result if you aggregate all your fetches in an array (e.g., `[getLastGame(teamArr[0]), getLastGame(teamArr[1]), getLastGame(teamArr[2]), etc.]`) and then loop over that array using `await` on each element.

```js
const timed = (id) => new Promise(res => {
  setTimeout(() => res(id), Math.random() * 2000);
})

const func = async () => {
  const promises = [timed(1), timed(2), timed(3), timed(4)];
  for (let promise of promises) {
    const returned = await promise;
    console.log(returned);
  }
}

func();
```

Something else you can consider is, again aggregating all your promises, but then using `Promise.all` to await the resolution of all of the promises to then do something when all your data have arrived:

```
Promise.all([getLastGame(teamArr[0]), getLastGame(teamArr[1], etc.)])
  .then(all => {
    // the `all` variable will contain an array of all resolved promises
  })
```